# Twitter gem: how to avoid searching deeply with max_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I want my app to search tweets with a specific #tag on Twitter every few minutes, like this:

```
results = client.search("#mypopulartag")
```

However, I don't want to do a full search each time. In building the app, I've encountered the Twitter::TooManyRequests error, because it returns a lot of results (presumably the Twitter gem makes as many requests to Twitter as needed for one `client.search()` call).

I don't need it to search super deep each time. Can I pass in the `max_id` parameter to the client.search method, so I don't waste API calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you keep track of the id of the most recent tweet that you've processed, you can get all tweets since then with something like this (using gem version 5.13):

```
  client.search(
    "#mypopulartag",
    result_type: 'recent',
    since_id: since_id   # your last processed id
  ).take(15)
```

Just keep in mind that if there are, say, 60 results, you'll need to execute more `client.search` calls to get all the tweets.  For those calls, you'd want to also specify a `max_id` equal to the last tweet id that was processed in the current search.

Comment: Ah, I see. But why would I have to execute more `client.search` calls if there are many (~60) new results since my last search? My understanding is that `client.search` (with the `.take(15)` omitted) makes as many requests as necessary to the Twitter search API- is that incorrect?

Comment: The reason I think the gem makes many requests to Twitter for one `client.search` call is because when I do `client.search("#nike")` or any other very popular tag, it takes forever and returns a bunch of results, and if I make another request immediately after, it gives me `Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`.

Comment: Just tried `client.search("#tag", result_type: "recent", since_id: id_of_my_last_saved_tweet)` and it returned all 4500 results (only about 20 tweets were made since my last query. I also tried passing a max_id, but it also did not seem to have an effect. Any ideas why those parameters do not seem to be working? Thanks.

Comment: What version of the gem are you using?

Comment: Here's a sample that works for me: 

  `#get the id of the third tweet`
  `three_tweets_ago = client.search("#hashtag", result_type: "recent").take(10)[2].id`
  `client.search("#hashtag", result_type: "recent", since_id: three_tweets_ago).count`
  `# result is 3, as expected`